# Hide the parent header when iframe child scroll down

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I'm trying to hide the website header when scrolling down in the child iFrame. please help!
i did find this script but i dont know how to link it to my iframe.

```js
// Hide Header on on scroll down
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    
    // Make sure they scroll more than delta
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;
    
    // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
    // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
        }
    }
    
    lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

Comment: Say you have one iframe on the page, you can access script (access variables or call functions) of that iframe by window.frames[0]

Comment: And in your iframe script, you can access script of main page by window.parent